# "Noter que" ou "Notez que" ?

Tags: grammaire, formulation, pronoms-impersonnels

Dans un document sérieux (style académique), il faut éviter de d'exprimer à la première ou deuxième personne (tout doit être impersonnel). J'hésite cependant à utiliser "notez que" à la place de "noter que" qui me paraît moins correct:

> On peut aussi définir un demi-soustracteur. Notez que la soustraction n'est pas commutative !

> On peut aussi définir un demi-soustracteur. Noter que la soustraction n'est pas commutative !

Laquelle des deux phrases choisiriez-vous ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"On remarquera/notera", "Nota Bene" sont des formules impersonnelles qui permettent d'éviter ce "Notez", impropre aux tournures académiques et, de surcroît, rendu un peu dirigiste par la finale exclamative.

"Relevons que", "Notons" sont à la première personne d'un point de vue grammatical, mais c'est une première personne impersonnelle : ce "nous" a ici valeur de "on" et ne s'adresse à personne en particulier. Il ne s'agit pas réellement d'une entité collective dont ferait partie l'auteur (il ne va pas noter lui-même ce qu'il recommande à son lecteur de noter), et n'a donc rien d'un "nous" réel.

Toutes me semblent acceptables dans un mémoire ou une thèse. Le point d'exclamation l'est moins, à mon sens. Surtout s'il s'attache à la non-commutativité de la soustraction (laquelle me semble trop élémentaire et bien connue pour être l'objet de passions si vives qu'elles exigent un point d'exclamation).

Comment: Très clair et complet, merci ! (si vous me permettez le point d'exclamation)

Comment: Ha ha ! Allez, je te dis merde, pour ton papier.

Answer (score 1):

La formule correcte est "notez".

Pour adopter une tournure impersonnelle, on pourrait écrire p.ex. "on peut noter que, etc."

Comment: Pas une alternative équivalente, mais plus précisément de la nature injonctive de « Noter que » ou « Notez que » : « Il est à noter que », « À noter que ».

Answer (score 1):

Les deux possibilités sont correctes et je crois qu'il n'existe pas de consensus académique bien déterminé. Voilà par exemple deux exemples tirés de la grammaire française de Grevisse et Goosse,  *Le Bon Usage*. Alternativement ils emploient dans leur grammaire « il faut noter que », « à noter que », qui sont utilisés cependant de façon très majoritaire dans les ouvrages académiques, avec « il est à noter que » et certaines variantes.  ([réf.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22noter%20que%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr))

Il me semble d'ailleurs que la différence entre « noter » et « à noter » est insubstantielle.

- *Il n'y a que la glace qui me voit* (E. et J. DE GONC., Man. Salomon, LXII). [Discours direct. Noter que voit est homophone de voie.]
- Dans d'autres cas, cela est exclu, comme si on était dans une zone neutre,
  ni subordination ni coordination, seulement asyndète (§ 275, b). Noter que
  les sous-phrases avec avoir beau peuvent être en incidente ou suivre l'autre
  sous-phrase : *Les lois de septembre*, ON A BEAU DIRE, *sont infiniment trop
  douces* ! (FLAUB., Êduc., II, 2.)

*Autres références*

[Jean Gerson Commentateur Dionysien - Page 130 - 1973](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Jean_Gerson_Commentateur_Dionysien/lW-nEzzmtVIC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22noter+que%22&pg=PA130&printsec=frontcover) Noter que le même verset de psaume sera parfois goûté de façon tout autre que jamais auparavant ou dans la suite . Noter qu'il est difficile de faire comprendre ou goûter beaucoup de choses , qui sont très claires , à des malades ou à ...

[Le vocabulaire des sentiments dans les textes sumériens: ... - Page 90 - 2007](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Le_vocabulaire_des_sentiments_dans_les_t/SGZtAAAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22noter+que%22&dq=%22noter+que%22&printsec=frontcover) Noter que ib(-ba) a connu le .

[Sciences géologiques: Bulletin - Volume 27 - Page 208 - 1974](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Sciences_g%C3%A9ologiques/LyAhAQAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22noter+que%22&dq=%22noter+que%22&printsec=frontcover) Noter que, dans ce cas de remplissage, contrairement à b, les dolomites de bordure peuvent être peu corrodées et elles ne renferment pratiquement pas de microéléments de remplacement.

[Revue d'égyptologie - Volumes 17 à 18 - Page 17 - 1965](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Revue_d_%C3%A9gyptologie/fkkHAQAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22noter+que%22&dq=%22noter+que%22&printsec=frontcover) Noter que le copte possède tin mot tg&tg var. uj&ujt, cgtktgq, tg&igqT (Crum, Copt. Dict., p. 604 b) « among parts of buildings» qui désignerait selon les commentateurs « montants de porte », «balcon» ou «latrines».

[Le sacrement de mariage - 2015](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Le_sacrement_de_mariage/_Kj4DQAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22noter+que%22&pg=PT66&printsec=frontcover) Noter que, pour l'Église, la soumission de la femme ne fait pas partie des conditions d'un mariage valide.

[Programme mondial de recensement de l’agriculture 2020:  - 2018](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Programme_mondial_de_recensement_de_l_ag/NR1dDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22noter+que%22&pg=PA183&printsec=frontcover) Noter que la Classe 9.01 (Graminées et autres cultures fourragères) concerne uniquement les cultures destinées à l'alimentation animale.

[Linear B, a 1984 Survey - Page 181 - 1988](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Linear_B_a_1984_Survey/KGqus_attmEC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22noter+que%22&pg=PA181&printsec=frontcover)  Noter que mívws pourrait être issu de * Mivfws . – Il est possible que le pluriel Mlvớai ait désigné originellement les rois successifs d'une certaine dynastie d'orchomène